# C#/XML Reading XML File doesnt work

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf, file-io

I want to read an XML-File and save the InnerText-Strings but it crashes with a SystemNullReference error. I think the way I read it is wrong but I'm not sure.

XML-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
<schema>
  <Hintergrund>#FFFFFFFF</Hintergrund>
  <Zahlen>#FFFFFFFF</Zahlen>
  <Text>#FFFFFFFF</Text>
  <Zeichenketten>#FFFFFFFF</Zeichenketten>
  <Tags>#FF000000</Tags>
  <Direktiven>#FF000000</Direktiven>
  <Ausdruecke>#FF000000</Ausdruecke>
  <Initialisierer>#FF000000</Initialisierer>
  <Modifizierer>#FF000000</Modifizierer>
  <Booleanische>#FF000000</Booleanische>
  <Operator>#FF000000</Operator>
  <Kommentare>#FF000000</Kommentare>
</schema>
```

Reading:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("/schema/*"))
{
    switch (node.Name)
    {
        case "Hintergrund":
            colorBG = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(node["Hintergrund"].InnerText);
            break;
        case "Zahlen":
            colorNumbers = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(node["Zahlen"].InnerText);
            break;
        case "Text":
            colorText = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(node["Text"].InnerText);
            break;
        case "Zeichenketten":
            colorStrings = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(node["Zeichenketten"].InnerText);
            break;
        case "Tags":
            colorTags = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(node["Tags"].InnerText);
            break;
        case "Direktiven":
            colorDirectives = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(node["Direktiven"].InnerText);
            break;
        case "Ausdruecke":
            colorStatements = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(node["Ausdruecke"].InnerText);
            break;
        case "Initialisierer":
            colorInitial = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(node["Initialisierer"].InnerText);
            break;
        case "Modifizierer":
            colorModifiers = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(node["Modifizierer"].InnerText);
            break;
        case "Booleanische":
            colorBools = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(node["Booleanische"].InnerText);
            break;
        case "Operator":
            colorOperators = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(node["Operator"].InnerText);
            break;
        case "Kommentare":
            colorComments = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(node["Kommentare"].InnerText);
            break;
    }   
}
```

Please tell me why it doesn't works.

Comment: Well which line is failing? What diagnostics have you already tried?

Comment: Is that switch statement necessary? All of those elements contain colours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're currently trying to get the `Text` node *within* the `Text` element, etc - but there isn't one.

I suspect you want something like:

```
case "Text":
    colorText = (Color) ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(node.InnerText);
```

Alternatively, I'd just select the `schema` node itself, and use:

```
colorText = ConvertColor(node["Text"]);
colorBG = ConvertColor(node["Hintergrund"]);
// etc
```

where `ConvertColor` is something like:

```
Color ConvertColor(XmlNode node)
{
    return node == null ? null
                 : (Color) ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(node.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It work's. I'll mark it as answer as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

You need to write node.InnerXml or node.InnerText to read each element